# servicestack and ormlite database auto generation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

In [servicestack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack) and [ormlite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite)
How do you auto generate database and seed it the first time it is accessed when using code first approach and you have a valid connection to the database server.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use ServiceStack's [AutoQuery AutoGen](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-autogen) feature if you're asking about auto generating APIs and POCO data models for your existing RDBMS tables.

If you want to generate Tables from POCO Data Models you would use [OrmLite Create Table APIs](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/apis/schema), e.g:

```cs
using var db = appHost.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open();

if (db.CreateTableIfNotExists<Person>())
{
    db.Insert(new Person { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe" });
}
```

Comment: Thank you.I am talking about the second senario.where do I put that code to generate and seed the database the first time it is accessed

Comment: Well am new to servicestack.l am looking for an optimal point to generate and seed the database.

Comment: Also does that snippet generate the entire database or I have to do that for every table

Comment: @johnka You'd create tables anywhere in your App's Startup, e.g. in AppHost.Configre(). The [Create Table APIs](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/apis/schema) are APIs for creating Tables. There's no "entire database" concept & tables aren't limited to a single database, i.e. they can be used to create/query tables in the ADO .NET Connection DB commands are executed on.

Comment: Ok.Thanks.I will use AppHost.Configre()